# Meaning of dich right after subject in german questions

Tags: german-to-english, grammar-identification

> Q: Warum konntest du  dich nicht hinlegen?
>
> Translation: Why can't you lay down?

My question is what is the purpose of 'dich' in this sentence? I tried to translate the sentence without dich into English through google translate, and it seems they both mean the same.

Comment: Google translate is not a good test of grammar. It will take whatever gibberish you type in, grammatical or not, and make a guess about what you meant. So if you leave out *dich* GT will fill it in for you before translating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not because it's a question. You have this reflexive pronoun also in statements and commands:

> Du legst dich hin.
> Leg dich hin!

Note that the verb *hinlegen* is a separable verb, so in many tenses it becomes *legen + hin,* but this not the topic of your question.

The verb *hinlegen* is a transitive verb. Transitive verbs also exist in English. These are verbs that mandatorily require an object. A sentence with a transitive verbs is incomplete without an object.

Some examples from english grammar:

- to require:

  - wrong:

    > These are verbs that mandatorily require.

    You must tell what the verbs require. The sentence is incomplete without this information.
  - correct:

    > These are verbs that mandatorily require **an object.**
- to wear:

  - wrong:

    > Tom wears.

    Here is missing what Tom is wearing. The sentence is incomplete without this part.
  - correct:

    > Tom wears **a hat.**

Also in German many verbs are transitive:

- bedürfen:

  > wrong: Der Schüler bedarf.
  > <sup>The student needs.</sup>
  > correct: Der Schüler bedarf **eines kompetenten Lehrers.** (Genitive object)
  > <sup>The student needs **a competent teacher.**</sup>
- gehören:

  > wrong: Dieses Haus gehört.
  > <sup>This house belongs.</sup>
  > correct: Dieses Haus gehört **dem Bürgermeister.** (Dative object)
  > <sup>This house belongs **to the mayor.**</sup>
- kennen:

  > wrong: Georg kennt.
  > <sup>Georg knows.</sup>
  > correct: Georg kennt **den Weg.** (Accusative object)
  > <sup>Georg knows **the way.**</sup>

And in German *hinlegen* also belongs to the class of transitive verbs:

> wrong: Simon legt hin.
> correct: Simon legt **die Blumen** hin.

Most transitive verbs can also be used reflexive. This means, that the subject and the object are identical. To indicate this, you use a reflexive pronoun as object in German and also in English:

> transitive: Maria wäscht **ihr Auto.**
> <sup>Maria washes **her car.**</sup>
> reflexive: Maria wäscht **sich.**
> <sup>Maria washes **herself.**</sup>

In English you can omit this reflexive pronoun in many cases:

> Maria washes **herself.** = Maria washes.
> Markus lays down **himself.** = Markus lays down.

This is not possible in German. For some verbs it is possible, but then it changes the meaning:

- Maria wäscht sich.
  This means that Maria is cleaning her body with water (and maybe soap or something similar).
- Maria wäscht.
  This means, that Maria is washing something. The most likely meaning is, that she does the laundry. It definitely does NOT mean, that she is washing herself.

But *"Markus legt hin"* does mean nothing. This is just a wrong sentence. The word *hinlegen* is a verb that mandatorily requires an object that tells what Markus is laying down. And if he lays down himself, you have to say it in German.

---

Note, that there is another difference between German and English: English has no proper reflexive verbs. You can use transitive verbs in a reflexive manner, just as discussed above, but in English there is no verb that can't be used other than reflexive. In other words: When ever you find a verb that is used reflexive in English, you can use the same verb transitive too. This is true in English but false in German.

German has a lot of proper reflexive verbs, i.e. verbs, that always must be used reflexive. A usage of such a verb without a reflexive pronoun is wrong. *Hinlegen* does not belong to this class, because it can be used transitive too, but here are some German proper reflexive verbs:

- freuen

  > Ich freue **mich.**
  > <sup>I am happy.</sup>

  The correct translation of *"I am happy"* is *"Ich bin fröhlich"* or *"Ich bin glücklich"* which both have a similar meaning as *"Ich freue mich."* It is not possible to translate *"Ich freue mich."* into an English sentence that uses the same grammatical construction as the German sentence.
- interessieren

  > Barbara interessiert **sich** für Philosophie.
  > <sup>Barbara is interested in philosophy.</sup>

  Same situation as before. The English sentence is in German *"Barbara ist an Philosophie interessiert."* Which means quite the same, but is an unusual construction in German. (Note that here the word *interessiert* is not a verb but an adjective.) The German sentence with the reflexive pronoun can't be translated into an English sentence that uses the same construction.

Other examples are

> Bitte setzen Sie **sich.** - Please sit down.
> Das Buch befindet **sich** in meiner Tasche. - The book is in my bag.
> Herr Mayer beschwert **sich** über den Tee. - Mr. Mayer complains about the tea.

Comment: Why is it not a question even with the question mark?

Comment: @user688539: It is a question, but the fact that it is a question does not affect the issue.

Comment: It is possible to use "to lay down" reflexively in poetry. I think the most famous example is in the Simon & Garfunkel song "Bridge over Troubled Water": "... I will lay me down". It's not used that way in normal speech though. I'm not sure when English lost it's reflexive verbs, but I gather that most other European languages do have them so English is the outlier in this case. German has more complex forms of reflexive verbs as well, for example: *Zieh dir deinen Mantel an.* *Ich passe mich der Kälte an.*

Answer (score 0):

"hinlegen" is transitive. It must have an object to operate with -"something to be laid". In this case you lay "yourself" down. Without "dich" the sentence stays incomplete.

If you do "hinlegen" with something different - not with yourself, it will be most probably translated as "put".